# Output JSON objects to separate lines

Tags: json, output

I have some JSON data in a list which I need to output to a single file but I need each JSON object to be placed on a separate line.

This is how the data is looking right now when i use the following code:

```
with open('FW_rules_adj.json', 'w') as file:
        json.dump(FWruleList, file)
```

```
[{'protocol': 'any', 'srcPort': 'Any', 'srcCidr': '10.1.10.0/24', 'destPort': 'Any', 'destCidr': 'tennis.com', 'policy': 'allow', 'syslogEnabled': False, 'comment': 'Line 1'}, {'protocol': 'any', 'srcPort': 'Any', 'srcCidr': '10.1.10.0/24', 'destPort': 'Any', 'destCidr': 'yahoo.com', 'policy': 'allow', 'syslogEnabled': False, 'comment': 'Line 2'}, {'protocol': 'any', 'srcPort': 'Any', 'srcCidr': '10.1.10.0/24', 'destPort': 'Any', 'destCidr': 'ninemsn.com.au', 'policy': 'allow', 'syslogEnabled': False, 'comment': 'Line 3'}]
```

but, I need it to go into one file like so:

```
{"protocol":"any", "srcPort":"Any", "srcCidr":"any", "destPort":"Any", "destCidr":"tennis.com", "policy":"allow", "syslogEnabled":false, "comment":"Line 1"}
{"protocol":"any", "srcPort":"Any", "srcCidr":"any", "destPort":"Any", "destCidr":"yahoo.com", "policy":"allow", "syslogEnabled":false, "comment":"Line 2"}
{"protocol":"any", "srcPort":"Any", "srcCidr":"any", "destPort":"Any", "destCidr":"ninemsn.com.au", "policy":"allow", "syslogEnabled":false, "comment":"Line 3"}
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write a newline character after each call to `dump`:

```
with open('FW_rules_adj.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(FWruleList, file)
    file.write("\n")
```

Make sure not to change the `dump` format into something that will add newlines in the encoded JSON, or the file will become much harder to read later.